# On Python TextBlob : limit size of model when update

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, textblob

I am working on categorize texts using TextBlob on Python and NaiveBayesClassifier.

The goal is to do continuous learning, which is made possible on NaiveBayesClassifier by using the update method.

But there's a problem : the classifier grow and grow and grow without limit !

How I can set a limit or "clean" the classifier from useless data after update ?

Looking in the sources in NLTK ( https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html ) I didn't saw anything useful.